# How to place add data on JavaFX TableView (Scene Builder) with JSON data

Tags: java, json, javafx

Currently I can retrieve the data of JSON from `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums`.

As of now, I can parse the json data and call everyfield of it. The JSON includes the fields of `id, userId, title`

In my code, I declare them below

`int id,userId`

`String title`

and this is the current Output

[image]

Now I'm trying to place these values to `FXML file` to my `Home.fxml`

my Table View has columns of `id,userId,title` and these columns has `fx:id` of

`field1, field2, field3`

Here's the fxml

[image]

and the `fx:id` of `TableView` is `fx:id="tableView"`

What I want to try is to place the parsed data of JSON  into the Table View. But I don't have idea how can I place them all.

My `Main` file codes

```
 public class Main extends Application {

private static HttpURLConnection connection;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    BufferedReader reader;
    String line;
    StringBuffer responseContent = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Request Setup

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);

        int status = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (status > 299){
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
        } else {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        }
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            responseContent.append(line);
        }

        reader.close();
        parse(responseContent.toString());
    }

    catch (MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        connection.disconnect();
    }


    Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml")));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Home");
    primaryStage.show();


}

public static String parse(String responseBody){
    JSONArray albums = new JSONArray(responseBody);
    for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++){
        JSONObject album = albums.getJSONObject(i);
        int id = album.getInt("id");
        int userId = album.getInt("userId");
        String title = (String) album.get("title");
        System.out.println(id + " | " + title + " | " + userId);

    }
    return null;
}
public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: Create a model class that represents the JSON data as an object. For instance, create a class named `Album` which has `id`, `userId` and `title` properties. Could even use a library that automatically maps `Album` instances to JSON and vice versa. Then configure the `TableView` to display `Album` instances, similar to how you would configure a table for any other class—see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm

Comment: please don't post screenshots for text output (hard to read) - instead, c&p the text

Comment: I prefer `GSON` over the current API that you are using for things like this.